# MySQL query not working when using php variable in where clause

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I'm trying to compare a PHP variable $emplID in a MYSQL where (uid=) clause. The value of this variable is 999. Directly assigning the value to the variable works fine. Using the variable that has been obtained during an earlier MYSQL fetch does not.

I've spend several hours trying to find a solution without any result.

The database column uid is varchar. I have also tried to do it using int.

I suspected it might be some hidden character like a null terminator or a difference in variable type. Var_dumps however show no difference whatsoever between the directly assigned value and the obtained variable value. string(3) "999"

I fiddled a lot with the quotation marks to see if I did something wrong there. (and uid= '$uid'"); and uid= $uid"); and uid= '".$uid."'");

I noted that upon adding a var dump, print_r or echo after $uid = $emplID; it also no longer works with a directly value assigned variable. I suspect this points in the direction of the underlying problem here.

I feel like I'm missing something simple here. But unfortunately can't get a hold of it.

```
 $sqlempl = "SELECT `id` FROM `EMPLOYERS` WHERE `Name` = '".$emplNAME."'"; 
        $result = $connection->query($sqlempl);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "employer id: ";
                $emplID = $row["id"]; 
                //echo $emplID;
            }
        } else {
            echo "ERROR4";
        }
}


//$emplID = "999";  


$uid = $emplID;  // set your user id settings
$datetime_string = date('c',time());    

if(isset($_POST['action']) or isset($_GET['view']))
{
  if(isset($_GET['view']))
  {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $start = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_GET["start"]);
    $end = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_GET["end"]);
    // $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_GET["uid"]);

    $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT `id`, `start` ,`end` ,`title` FROM  `events` where (date(start) >= '$start' AND date(start) <= '$end') and uid= '$uid'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $events[] = $row; 
    }
    echo json_encode($events); 
    exit;
```

Comment: You're mixing POST and GET arrays here and it's unknown what the sources are.

Comment: The `while` loop keeps overwriting the `$emplID` variable. It will just contain the value from the last row. Can the first query really return more than one row? If not, why do you read the results in a loop?

Comment: Why not just join the queries instead of doing two queries?

Comment: You are right, it does not need to be read in a loop. However, there cannot ever be more than one result since the emplID is unique.

I'm using $uid throughout the code, so getting uid is actually my first query in the whole code. Then it makes sense - to me - not to combine queries every time, but to just use a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a good reason why it's failing. The way a variable is assigned has no effect on the future code that uses it.

However, you can avoid this whole thing by simply joining the two queries.

```
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,"
        SELECT ev.`id`, ev.`start` ,ev.`end` ,ev.`title` 
        FROM  `events` AS ev
        JOIN EMPLOYERS AS em ON ev.uid = em.id
        where date(ev.start) BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'
        AND em.name = '$emplName'");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using $uid throughout the code, so getting uid is actually my first query in the whole php file. Then it makes sense - to me - not to combine queries every time, but to just use a variable. I will however check whether your suggestion works like it should out of curiosity and a possible work around for now.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot get this to work either. 
I noted something strange though. When I add a var dump, print_r or echo after $uid = $emplID; it also no longer works with a directly value assigned variable. I suspect this points in the direction of the underlying problem here.

Comment: Maybe an encoding problem?

Comment: Why are you using a `VARCHAR` column to hold a numeric ID?

Comment: I have tried using an integer as well to rule out this had anything to do with it. This did not get me any further unfortunately. Also in future the ID might very well be a99 or 1b2.

Comment: (an integer column in the database)

Comment: Does the join query work if you try it by hand rather than from PHP?